# Como atribuir uma função em um botão do kivy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-kivy, kivy

Sou iniciante no python e quero que sempre que um determinado botão seja apertado, execute uma função. Aqui está o código:

**application.py**

```
import kivy
kivy.require("1.8.0")

from kivy.app import App

class application(App):
    def printar(self):
        print("Hello World")
        
application().run()
```

**application.kv**

```
BoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"
    BoxLayout:
        spacing: 130
        padding: [30, 30, 30, 30]
        size_hint: [1, .1]
        orientation: "horizontal"
        
        Button:
            id: option
            text: "Options"
            
        Label:
            text: "Connected"
            bold: True
            color: [0, 1, 0, .8]
            font_name: "DejaVuSans"
            
        Button:
            id: onoff
            text: "On/Off"
            
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "horizontal"
        spacing: 20
        padding: [30, 30, 30, 30]
        
        TextInput:
            size_hint: [.7, .05]
            pos_hint: {"y": .5}
            multiline: False
            hint_text: "Write"
        
        Button:
            id: send
            text: "Send"
            size_hint: [.2, .05]
            pos_hint: {"y": .5}
            on_release: root.printar()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def printar(self):
   print("ação")


Button:
    id: option
    text: "Options"
    on_press: root.printar()
```

Sempre que houver uma ação no botão a função chamada  printar()  sera iniciada, se só chamar a função "printar()" não sera encontrada  tem que fazer referencia a instancia.

Pode fazer a parte das especificações diretamente no código python qual tipo de layout:

```
import kivy
kivy.require("1.8.0")

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxLayout import BoxLayout


class Programa(BoxLayout):
    def printar(self):
       print("inicado")

class application(App):
    pass
        

iniciar.application()
iniciar.run()




<Programa@BoxLayout>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    ...resto do código
        
        Button:
            id: option
            text: "Options"
            on_press: root.printar()
```